# Search files in awesome windows manager

Tags: awesome-wm

I have recently switched to awesome windows manager. There I find only way to open an application is from menu option or directly typing command from run prompt <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + 
<kbd>r</kbd> . But there is no feature for search files and folders as in unity/gnome. Is such feature available in awesome or can be added in custom way?

I tried to search on google but couldn't find any relevant result. Neither awesome irc channel has good amount of users.

Comment: "Neither awesome irc channel" Which ones did you check? I only know about one, which other ones are there?

Comment: I checked on freenode. But in title there, they have mentioned link of another irc server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like the Nautilus file manager? You can install nautilus through your file manager and start it in awesome.